# mybatis - support for xml data type in SQL Server

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, ibatis

Environment:  Java + Spring + mybatis
In SqlServer, I have a table with xml data type.

Is this supported out-of-the-box with mybatis? If not, can this column be directly mapped in the resultset as jdbc/java type to be xml? Sample code would be very handy to understand.

Is there any other work-around?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know MyBatis does not support XML out of the box (the list of implicit type handlers is [here](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/configuration.html#typeHandlers)). But you can create your own type handler to handle unsupported or non-standard types.

Depending on the JDBC driver you are using you might work directly with XML ([java.sql.SQLXML](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/SQLXML.html)) or treat the XML [as a string type](http://nativexmldatabase.com/2010/03/01/xml-support-in-jdbc-4-0-the-sqlxml-interface/). Either way, you need to write your own MyBatis type handler.